# Leer atributos de elementos creados por los métodos .html () JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con JQuery, mi pregunta es la siguiente, en primer lugar yo hago una consulta a la base de datos por ajax y las consultas las agrego a un  mediante el método .html () de JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'controllers/select/listarParedes.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(respuesta){
        let Transportes = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        let lista = '';
        Transportes.forEach(e => {
            lista += `
            <option value="${e.id_opcion}">${e.nombre}</option>
            `
        });
        $('#txt_pared').html(lista);
    }
});
```

ahora bien, resulta que por motivos de otro método, yo necesito volver a llamar a esa función, pero esta vez, tengo que recorrer el  para ver cuales opciones coinciden con datos que tengo guardados en la base de datos, y a esas opciones aplicar el atributo "selected". Ya intente de muchas maneras recorrer los  dentro del  pero por algún motivo no funciona, esto es lo ultimo que he probado:

```
$('#txt_pared option').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

No se si el motivo por lo que pasa esto, es porque los  dentro del  los creo el mediante el método .html() de JQuery, alguien me lo podría aclarar? :(

Comment: $(this).val() le va a pertener al select y no a los options, para ellos sustituye el `.val()` con `.html()` o por `.text()`